# ActionBar aka Toolbar is black after upgrade to Support Library v21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I have just upgraded to the newest library version after Android Lollipop was released. After I fixed serveral doublicated attributes (which where caused by the Support Library) I updated my [`android-switch-backport`](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport/), and it compiled again.

However now I have no more the ActionBar, it is now a Toolbar. So far so good, but now is that Toolbar black and I have no idea why.

So how can I change it back to my custom colors, I used [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator), for generating all required resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a quiet long search I found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#SupportLib), that I need to defind the colors in the theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/secondary_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
</style>
```

Now I can remove the images generated by the Android Action Bar Style Generator, since I don't need them anymore.

Comment: Try to use Toolbar it is even more awesome. :)

Comment: @AhmedNawaz What is the real differance? I did not find any except that it has some more features.

Comment: @rekire toolbar is part of parent layout,you can place it anywhere and can do anything like normal view