# Doesn't get Light Text in ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm stuck with the `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`. I need a dark actionbar with white text.

[image: Dark ActionBar]

But that is what i get:

[image: Wrong Dark ActionBar]

I have a `PreferenceActivity` where i need this bar, after research i found the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455363/1809221

I have exactly the same.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note, you can use a standard `AppCompatActivity` along with the newly released [Preferences Support Library](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T) rather than using `PreferenceActivity` if that may be easier.

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake i have switch to PreferenceFragmentCompat but how can i start it? If i would start it it says it must extends from android.app.Fragment

Comment: Sounds like you are using `getFragmentManager()` rather than `getSupportFragmentManager()` - check that and your imports (it should be the v4 `FragmentTransaction` for instance).

Comment: Ok, what a stupid mistake from me. It's solved. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead using the new [Preferences Support Library](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T) along with `AppCompatActivity` rather than using `PreferenceActivity` at all.