# Android: How to show title bar in Preferences Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, preferences, titlebar

I have searched the forums, but can't seem to figure out how to show a title bar in the Android Preferences Fragment.  I see questions about how to hide it, but not about how to show it.

I have a preferences activity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

And I have a preferences fragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

And I have a preferences xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/title">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="regular"
```

However there is no title bar at the top of the preferences screen.  Any ideas how to make one show?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509180/no-actionbar-in-preferenceactivity-after-upgrade-to-support-library-v21

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/

Answer (score -2):

You mean show title bar in the fragment?
   
    you can try to inherit AppCompatActivity.

Comment: This should be a comment or Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue