# How to hide titlebar of nested preference on Gingerbread & Honeycomb

Tags: android, preferences

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455363/5969624) to construct settings of my application. My problem is that I get titlebar for nested `PreferenceScreen` elements. I tried to apply themes which turn off `windowTitle`. I tried to request window feature. But I was not successful. This problem is only on Gingerbread & Honeycomb. Post-Honeycomb everything works fine. Here is an image which shows two window titles one by me ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455363/5969624)), another by system.

[image]

Can someone help me to hide titlebar set by window? I am pretty sure it can be achieved but `Whatsapp` Developers won't answer me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to hide the titlebar with

```
        View titleView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if (titleView != null) {
            ((View)titleView.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

in accordance with the code in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455363/5969624) for Gingerbread & Honeycomb. Well with the if condition code can be written out of condition of being run only on Gingerbread & Honeycomb as post Honeycomb I have found `titleView != null` false.